# How to get notificated if there is new message while using while

Tags: python

I was doing bot that controls PC, and i created function to lock mouse and unlock it, but every time it was locked, it couldn't be unlocked. I don't know how to make it, please someone help me, i don't know python that much, here's the code

```
@bot.event

async def on_message(ctx):

    global locked, l
    if locked == True:
        unlock()
        l = True
        print(locked)

    if ctx.author == bot.user:
        return
    
    if ctx.content == "lock":

        lock(*pag.position())

    if ctx.content.startswith("move"):

        pos = ctx.content.split("-")[1].strip().split(",").strip()
        if locked:
            unlock()
            l = True
        pag.moveTo(pos)
        time.sleep(1)
        if l:
            lock()
    
    if ctx.content == "unlock":

        unlock()

    if l:

        locked = False
        l = False
        
    while locked:
        
        print(locked, x, y)
        if pag.position() != (x, y):
                
            try:

                pag.moveTo(x, y)
                
            except:

                pass

def lock(a, b):

    global locked, x, y
    x, y = a, b
    locked = True
    print(locked, x, y)


def unlock():

    global locked
    locked = False
```

I tried using while in on_message(), before on_message() and after on_message(), or every other method to put the while function, so i gave up and now i'm asking question
But nothing helped me

Comment: Is looks like this is a discord bot, which you want to use to lock the cursor?
I don't seem to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Harm Manders Yes, i want to create bot to lick cursor